Mathjax/latex/amsmath command for Unicode Character “⨳” (U+2A33)
I'm looking for a latex or amsmath shortcut for Unicode Character “⨳” (U+2A33)
. This gets used to denote the smash product as an infix. I looked online and tried detexify but got no results. Is there any major latex package that has this symbol?

I found it in The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List (https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) by searching the document for smash.

In unicode-math (or mathml in  a browser) or mathjax with a suitable font you could simply use ⨳
unicode-math for lualatex and xelatex, and compatible packages such as stix2 for pdflatex also define \smashtimes for this character.
mathjax rendering on math.stackexchange

